# onProxyRes of http-proxy-middleware doesn't work for same cases

Tags: node.js, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to write a proxy using `http-proxy-middleware` that modifies the content of the response, and set some headers.
I'm intercepting the reponse using `responseInterceptor` as the documentation says.

Here is the proxy implementation

```js
const proxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "http://www.google.com" ,

    changeOrigin: true,
    /**
     * IMPORTANT: avoid res.end being called automatically
     **/
    selfHandleResponse: true, // res.end() will be called internally by responseInterceptor()

    /**
     * Intercept response and replace 'Hello' with 'Goodbye'
     **/
    onProxyRes: responseInterceptor(async (responseBuffer, proxyRes, req, res) => {
        res.setHeader("custom-header", "header-value");
        const response = responseBuffer.toString('utf8'); // convert buffer to string
        return response.replaceAll('Hello', 'GoodBye'); // manipulate response and return the result
    }),
});
```

The issue is related with the target, for example for the target `google.com` it works perfectly, but using `notion.so` I'm getting an empty response buffer (so I can't modify it, neither the headers), but finnaly the proxy returns the response without any changes. Is onProxyRes calling before receiving the response of the server? Or I'm missing some configuration?